# How to step backwards in a path using Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I am searching through folders in order to find the one that has the contents that I desire.

```
$path = dir "C:\windows\ccmcache\*\Office.en-us" -Directory
echo $path
```

It returns:

```
Directory: C:\windows\ccmcache\c
```

But when I run my command:

```
Start-Process "$path\setup.exe /uninstall ProPlus /config Uninstall.xml" -Wait
```

It tries to run:

```
C:\windows\ccmcache\c\Office.en-us\setup.exe............
```

Which doesn't exist! So how can I go back a step so I can run the `setup.exe` command out of the ***`c` folder***?
Something like:

```
$path2 = $path\cd..
```

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
$Path2 = Resolve-Path (Join-Path $Path '..')
```

#### Note:

- `Join-Path` is the cross platform way of concatenating path strings
- `Resolve-Path` will give you a fully qualified path name

  - *^^ step is optional, since windows will traverse the `..` for you, but it helps to visually see the folder it resolves to.*

Does this help?

Comment: Yes! Thank you that is exactly what I was trying to ask.

Comment: This seems a little overboard for what the user needs. `$path` already knows its parent.

Comment: It is true, this was only suggested for understanding purposes and general use cases. As it seemed as the OP wanted an explanation as well as to how the pathing system works in PowerShell. While you could use the .NET props for this, it isn't as intuitive to a shell user as CMDLets.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `Get-ChildItem` to return a `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` object. The path you are looking for already exists there as the `Parent` property.

```
$path2 = $path.Parent.FullName
```

No other cmdlets are needed here. You don't even need to save it into another variable if you don't want to.

Beware that your `$path` could have multiple results which will have consequences later in your code. If you only cared about the first one you could add `| Select -First 1` to guarantee only one result.

Comment: Not even kidding I just ran into this problem of there being multiple files... your sir are awesome.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done simply using Resolve-Path function.
suppose structure is like following

```
              root
      Folder1      Folder2
```

and our current working directory is Folder1 and we want to move to Folder2.

```
$path2 = Resolve-Path("$path\..\Folder2\fileinFolder2")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand what you're asking.. Do you mean how to backtrack in your file directory? That command is "cd .."

Do you mean how to call $path THEN move one level higher in the directory? If so you'll need to create a new $var that is one level higher before calling your setup.exe

Comment: I'm sorry I am very new to Powershell. But when I do   $path2 = $path\cd.. it doesn't work. Could you show me a quick example of what that would look like?

Comment: It looks like @AP. beat me to it, check out his answer, it should accomplish what you're asking